# How to click the playback speed of a YouTube player using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I click the *Playback speed* setting in the YouTube player using Selenium with C#?

[image: Picture]

Alternatively, how can I add JavaScript into a Selenium project using C#?

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
    events: {
      'onReady': function(e){
        // e.target = player
        e.target.setPlaybackRate(0.5); // set to half speed
        e.target.playVideo(); // watch lolcats in slow motion :)
      },
    }`enter code here`
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, ensure the video link has loaded and passed all the ads etc..

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ytp-button.ytp-settings-button")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Playback speed')]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'0.5')]")).Click();
```

Comment: Please mark the answer the accepted if you found it useful, so that it can also help others.

Comment: Ok. Thank You! Do you have any other methods? with videos showing ads

Comment: There's many ways you could handle ads, you should search if there any other answers that have already tackled this. If not you should get to grips with deeper level selenium knowledge where you can then pick up some tips and tricks. For ads you could wait for the add element to dis-appear `var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector(".ytp-ad-text.ytp-ad-preview-text")));`